# init showing up as class method

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, initialization, singleton

I added `- (instancetype) init NS_UNAVAILABLE` to my class' public header.

When I try `[[MyClass alloc] init]` it shows a compiler error as expected, but `[MyClass init]` still shows up as an available class method. Is this normal? I cannot find any mention of `+ (instancetype) init` anywhere on the Internet.

Comment: What is the reason for not wanting an `init` method?

Comment: It's in an iOS 8.1 Cocoa Touch Framework project and the `init` method is declared in the `Project` visibility header for internal use only. The `Public` visibility header has `init` disabled.

Basically you can only obtain an instance of the class from other API calls and should not instantiate it yourself.

Comment: If you also add `+ (instancetype) init NS_UNAVAILABLE;` in your class init will not show.

Comment: Yes, but that's irrelevant. If there is no original `init` class method why is it even showing up?

Comment: Apple and its mysterious methods....No one knows this things except Apple. :)